# Making null values acceptable in richembed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am working with richembeds and variables and I need to make it acceptable for a variable with null value to still work in a richembed.

```
if (command === "stock") {
        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle("ACCOUNTS STOCK")
        .setTimestamp()
        .addField("Crunchyroll: ", crunchcodes.length)
        .addField("Disney +: ", discodes.length)
        .addField("Fortnite: ", fortcodes.length)
        .addField("HBO Now: ", hbocodes.length)
        .addField("Hulu: ", hulucodes)
        .addField("Mega.nz: ", megacodes.length)
        .addField("Minecraft: ", minecodes.length)
        .addField("Origin: ", origincodes.length)
        .addField("Spotify: ", spotcodes.length)
        .addField("Steam: ", steamcodes.length)
        .addField("UPlay: ", uplaycodes.length)
        .addField("VPN: ", vpncodes.length)
        message.channel.send({
            embed
        });

    }
```

Here is the error I currently get too just in case:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: RichEmbed field values
>   may not be empty

Comment: None of those variables can be null (besides `hulucodes`, but I'm assuming that's a typo and should be `hulucodes.length`?)

Answer (score 0):

You can add full blank field

```
.addBlankField(inline)
```

Or add something like this

```
if (command === "stock") {
        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        embed.setTitle("ACCOUNTS STOCK")
        embed.setTimestamp()
        if(somethinkg) {
            embed.addField("Crunchyroll: ", crunchcodes.length)
        } else {
            embed.addField("Crunchyroll: ", "\u200B")
        }
        embed.addField("Disney +: ", discodes.length)
        embed.addField("Fortnite: ", fortcodes.length)
        embed.addField("HBO Now: ", hbocodes.length)
        embed.addField("Hulu: ", hulucodes)
        embed.addField("Mega.nz: ", megacodes.length)
        embed.addField("Minecraft: ", minecodes.length)
        embed.addField("Origin: ", origincodes.length)
        embed.addField("Spotify: ", spotcodes.length)
        embed.addField("Steam: ", steamcodes.length)
        embed.addField("UPlay: ", uplaycodes.length)
        embed.addField("VPN: ", vpncodes.length)
        message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary expression like this :

```js
embed.addField("Disney +:", discodes.length ? discodes.length : DefaultValueToShow);

// DefaultValueToShow has to be a stringeable value
```

With this you can set a default value to show if `discodes.length` is `undefined`, `null` or `false`.
Finally for all that is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).